# Is there any way to enable for(int i=0; ... in gcc without having to turn on c99 mode

Tags: c, gcc, for-loop, c99, pragma

I've got a very big program which compiles with gcc without warnings.

If I turn on c99 mode --std=c99 on the command line, it gives a huge number of warnings and errors.

But I love the idiom `for(int i=0; i<20; i++){ code }`

in place of `{int i; for (i=0; i<20; i++){ code }}`

Is there any way to tell gcc to allow this and only this?

Alternatively, is there any way to enable c99 mode in the particular functions I'm working on? Something like

```
#pragma c99 on 

for(int i=0; i<99; i++)
{
    code
}

#pragma c99 off
```

Comment: ANSI C forbids the mix of declaration and statements for a reason. You should to declare all your variables at the top of your function and that's all. If you're afraid of losing them or mixing them, your function has too many lines and you should segment it.

Comment: What happens when you try compiling your code in the `gnu99` mode (as opposed to `c99`)?

Comment: This comment stands to "vote against" Eregrith's. There are good reasons why C89 allows you to define variables at the top of *any* block, not just a function body as Eregrith's style guide demands. There are also good reasons why few other languages, and very few modern languages, have any such requirement. Do not follow Eregrith's style, even in C89. The reason why C89 forbade the mix of definitions and other statements is a pretty weak one -- it was largely historical by 1989, and had to do with ponderous old compilers that laid down stack frames in a pretty simple way.

Comment: Get rid of the errors and warnings. Compiling with `-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` gives you a pretty good sense of portability for your code --- if you need to move it to another compiler or computer or whatever, it just works :)

Comment: @pmg: as long as you don't need to use MS's compiler. If you do, then the "safe" approach is to change `-std=c99` to `-std=c89`, and give up on using C99 features, including this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that the warnings and errors are because `-std=c99` requests standard-conforming C99, which means that many platform-specific functions that pollute the C99 namespace are not defined.

Instead, you should try `--std=gnu99`, which is the C99-equivalent to the default mode of `gnu89`.

Comment: Or better, use `-std=c99` and then define the correct feature test macros for what you want to use (probably `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to use **-std=gnu99** you can disable individual warnings:

```
-Wno-declaration-after-statement
```

Read **info gcc**:

```
`-Wdeclaration-after-statement (C and Objective-C only)'
     Warn when a declaration is found after a statement in a block.
     This construct, known from C++, was introduced with ISO C99 and is
     by default allowed in GCC.  It is not supported by ISO C90 and was
     not supported by GCC versions before GCC 3.0.  *Note Mixed
     Declarations::.
```

Comment: The problem is that it's an *error*, not a warning, when you're in c89 mode.